# Starting with the 5e Starter set

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-beginner-box

I just bought the D&D 5e starter set, being interested in the game for quite some time now. I've read through most of the rule book now and a lot of things are more clear to me at the moment, but, as it's a lot of information, pretty much still isn't. I've looked around on YouTube, hoping to find beginner video guides for 5e that really talk about how to start a game from scratch, what to do first (not creating characters, I want to begin by using the ones that are in the box first to learn how to play the game), what comes after that, and so on.

1) we're completely new. What's the best and quickest way to start with the starter set without finding other people? Is playing through The Mines Of Phandelver (hope I got that right) and looking things up in the rules while doing so an option? Because I think that'll ruin the experience.

2) Are there good step-by-step videos on how to play the game from the beginning? Like a 'D&D 5e for dummies'' video edition in which I can see what happens, what needs to be done and so on. Something like the videos I mentioned above, if you know those.Those were great. If there aren't, could you perhaps suggest something else?

3) I have a possible group of 3-4 people (including myself), while the game is supposed to be played by 4-5 people (not including myself). I read that this can easily be solved by dividing the number of monsters by two and doing the same with boss HP, but us this really all that needs to be done? Also, won't this make the game less fun? I hope this helps and my questions are able to be answered! Thanks for responding :)

Comment: I think this needs to be narrowed down a bit. (Don't worry--you can ask ten separate questions and they'd all get addressed.) Some of the separate questions I see: (1) how can I find resources to help me (new GM) and my new players make our way through the starter set? (2) How do I modify the starter set for a smaller-than-average party? (3)-(*N*) *specific questions from the "pretty much still isn't" that you mention*.

Comment: I'll try to do that, haha. I tend to rattle on a lot.

1) we're completely new. What's the best and quickest way to start with the starter set without finding other people? Is playing through The Mines Of Phandelver (hope I got that right) and looking things up in the rules while doing so an option? Because I think that'll ruin the experience.

2) Are there good step-by-step videos on how to play the game from the beginning? Like a 'D&D 5e for dummies'' video edition in which I can see what happens, what needs to be done and so on. Something like the videos I mentioned above, if you know those

Comment: Those were great.
If there aren't, could you perhaps suggest something else?

3) I have a possible group of 3-4 people (including myself), while the game is supposed to be played by 4-5 people (not including myself). I read that this can easily be solved by dividing the number of monsters by two and doing the same with boss HP, but us this really all that needs to be done? Also, won't this make the game less fun?

I hope this helps and my questions are able to be answered! Thanks for responding :)

Comment: So I'd say go ahead and post each of those as a separate (new) question--from there each will get attention. Don't worry about spamming. The opposite's true, actually: smaller bites tend to work better here.